# The Game of Nim Loop

Tags: java, loops

So, I have to make a Java game in the style of Nim....and I have succeeded in making most of it...I just have a couple of questions that I'm confused on:

Question 1: The program executes fine, and it even runs once, but after going through the code once, the program quits...I need help seeing why it does that (Am I using the wrong loop?)

Question 2: Why does the program always choose the computer to be in the so-called "Smart Mode?"

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you guys :D

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class GameOfNim
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        Random num = new Random ();
        int numberLeft = num.nextInt(101-10) + 10;
        int computerMode = num.nextInt(1);
        int subtraction = numberLeft;
        boolean turn = num.nextBoolean();

        System.out.println ("The number you start out with is: " + numberLeft);

        if (computerMode == 0)
        {
            System.out.println ("The computer is in smart mode");
        }
        if (computerMode == 1)
        {
            System.out.println ("The computer is in dumb mode");
        }

        while (numberLeft > 1)
        {
            if (turn == true)
            {
                System.out.println ("It is your turn...");
                System.out.printf ("Please enter the number you wish to take from the pile (Remember it has to be less than " + numberLeft/2 + "): ");
                subtraction = in.nextInt();
                numberLeft -=subtraction;
                System.out.println ("The number left is " + numberLeft);
                turn = false;
            }
            if (turn ==false)
            {
                System.out.println ("It is the computer's turn...");
                if (computerMode == 0)
                {  
                    numberLeft = smartComputer(numberLeft);
                    System.out.println ("The number left is " + numberLeft);
                }

                if (computerMode == 1)
                {
                    numberLeft -= num.nextInt(numberLeft/2);
                    System.out.println ("The number left is " + numberLeft);
                }
                turn = true;
                return;
            }
        }

        if (numberLeft <= 1)
        {
            if (turn = false)
            {
                System.out.println ("You Win!");
            }  
            else
            {
                System.out.println ("You're horrible...you lost to a computer.");
            }  
        }
    }

    public static int smartComputer (int num)
    {
        int power = 2;        
        while (power < num) 
        { 
            power *=2;
        }
        power /= 2;
        num = power-1;
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well actually, I figured out the loop thingy, I just had to get rid of the return statement I wrote after the computer's turn...but I still have no idea why it won't choose the dumb version....

Comment: For your second question `int computerMode = num.nextInt(1);` will always return `0` entering into `smartmode` And for your 1st question can you add some more explanation what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) of Random:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the  specified value (exclusive).

"Exclusive" means that `nextInt(n)` will return an integer that could be `n-1` but can *not* be `n`.  `nextInt(n)` has `n` different possible results, including 0.

The simple fix is to make it `nextInt(2)`, since there are 2 possible modes.

Answer (score 3):

Random.nextInt(int n) will return an int value between 0 and n exclusive. Since you've computed computerMode as this:

```
int computerMode = num.nextInt(1);
```

computerMode will always return 0.

If there's only two modes that the computer can be in maybe you can use nextBoolean instead?

Comment: True, I could do that, but I just changed the 1 to a 2 and now it works brilliantly :D YAY

Answer (score 2):

Since you've indicated that you have solved your first question, I'll answer the second.

This line:

```
Int computerMode = num.nextInt(1)
```

Should be:

```
Int computerMode = num.nextInt(2)
```

Or perhaps something like

```
Boolean computerMode = num.nextBoolean()
```

According to the documentation for `Random#nextInt`:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)...

Consequently, since you're passing in the value 1, the only possible value that can be returned is 0. I suggested using the `nextBoolean` method as well, since it looks like you're using the `nextInt` method to generate a Boolean-like value anyways.